# YouCompleteMe suggests only "local" used code

Tags: c, vim, vim-plugin

I'm trying to use YCM for the first time so in order to make it work I decided to give a chance for the YCM-Generator, which generates the **.ycm_extra_conf.py** file automatically based on the makefile.

So far my program is just a simple hello world.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    printf("Hello World!");
    
    return 0;
}
```

I'm using the CMakeLists.txt trick to generate the makefile.

```
file(GLOB sources *.h *.c)
add_executable(Foo ${sources})
```

then after executing the YCM-Generator script, I get this output

> Running cmake in '/tmp/tmp_YknVy'... $ cmake
> /home/pedro/Desktop/Projetos/teste
>
> Running make... $ make -i -j4
>
> Cleaning up...
>
> Build completed in 1.5 sec
>
> Collected 2 relevant entries for C compilation (0 discarded).
>
> Collected 0 relevant entries for C++ compilation (0 discarded).
>
> Created YCM config file with 0 C flags

YCM plugin does find the .ycm_extra_conf.py file, but the auto-completion doesn't work right, for example, if I type "floa", it doesn't suggests "float", but It only suggests things that I used before like "int" or "printf".
Am I missing something or this is working as intended?

Comment: Who knows? You should try that generator's issue tracker if it has one and/or YCM's.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I fixed it.

For c it does require a .ycm_extra_conf.py , while a friend of mine could make it work without one in c++.

The auto complete only suggest automatically functions that were previously used, if you don't remember a function name you have to press `<Ctrl-Space>`

YCM-Generator didn't do the job, so I modified the example file myself following the comments.

If you are used to Visual Assist, the auto complete works but it's really weak if compared to VA, which is a shame... I really hope someone port that plugin to Linux.